# Copying IMPORTRANGE formulas so that they stay relative

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

How do I copy a formula in Google Sheets that has the address of another sheet in the formula?

Now I have to edit the formula for every cell because when I copy it, it does not stay relative. And when I state "another sheet" I mean doc with a different name (address) not just another page within the same sheet.

Comment: Please give an example of such a formula.

Comment: Here is an example: =IMPORTRANGE("1k4o8odd236MLxIbfM_jI71VwiDl1p--aYU1Sue1Wbz4","Dashboard!s8") except I have taken out several letters so as to protect my sheet. So now when I copy this into different document it will remain at S8 regardless of copying it down to 9, 10, 11 and so on.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, you could do things like

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1k4o8odd...","Dashboard!S"&row())
```

forming the range string for import based on the row of the current cell.

But I do not actually recommend this. You should not use `importrange` as an individual cell reference; it's a serious drag on performance. As the name suggests, its purpose is to import the **range** of all cells you are going to need (maybe the whole sheet you are referring to); put the imported range somewhere (on a separate sheet, perhaps) and work with that data normally. For example, use

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1k4o8odd...","Dashboard!S1:S")
```

once and then refer to those imported cells.

Answer (score 0):

IF You want to point to only that one cell You need to make your cell references inside the formula absolute with a "$" sign in front :

```
='Sheet1'!$A$1
```

if you want it dynamic, remove the $ signs:

```
=importrange("your doc url","'Dashboards'!$S"&Row())
```

Also you use importrange to refer to a different doc.

```
 =importrange("your doc url","'Dashboard'!$S$8")
```

Comment: Still not answering the question.

Comment: @NormalHuman he specifically says he wants s8 to stay static from what I understand, so I believe my edit DID answer the question

Comment: It's the opposite; the OP wants a relative reference. "it does not stay relative", says the question. "it will remain at S8 regardless of copying it down to 9, 10, 11" says the comment.

Comment: @NormalHuman sorry, i was interpreting his second comment as what he "wanted" to happen

Comment: Yes you are right Normal Human, by saying still not answering the question. I want it to be able to copy relative to the cell. I will give you the scenario: I use these for dealer sheets and so what I put on the master dashboard shows up in all the different dealer doc's (separate doc url) and so when I copy it just copies S8 into every cell and then I have to go in and edit each one to s9, s10, s11 and I think that there has got to be a way of copying it like you do in a regular sheet.

Comment: @user110382 See my answer, where I tried to explain that importrange should not be used like an individual cell reference, this is not what it's for.

Comment: I have tried the =IMPORTRANGE("1k4o8odd...","Dashboard!S1:S") solution and the works quite well. Thanks